# Sending SOAP 1.2

Tags: php, web-services, curl, soap

I have to send some data to a server using SOAP. I've implemented this but I'm getting an error.

The error is not a SOAP or PHP etc error, its an error result from their application protocol stuff.

The other side insist that its because I'm sending SOAP1.1 data and they require SOAP1.2. As far as I can tell I am sending 1.2.

To check I've created a simple page on my server to collect the headers and the data so I could see what's actually being sent.

Am I missing something, or based on what I send below is this in fact SOAP1.2 as I suspect?

PS, I checked this article to get more info on the differences:
http://wso2.com/library/articles/differentiating-between-soap-versions-looking-soap-message/
Thanks a million,

John

Headers:

```
SERVER: Array
(
    [CONTENT_LENGTH] => 1286
    [CONTENT_TYPE] => application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
    [DOCUMENT_ROOT] => /home/viewport/public_html
    [GATEWAY_INTERFACE] => CGI/1.1
    [GEOIP_ADDR] => 1.2.3.4
    [HTTP_ACCEPT] => */*
    [HTTP_EXPECT] => 100-continue
    [HTTP_HOST] => example.com
    [PATH] => /bin
    [QUERY_STRING] => 
    [REDIRECT_STATUS] => 200
    [REMOTE_ADDR] => 1.2.3.4
    [REMOTE_PORT] => 46608
    [REQUEST_METHOD] => POST
    [REQUEST_URI] => /soap/index.php
    [SCRIPT_FILENAME] => /home/example/public_html/soap/index.php
    [SCRIPT_NAME] => /soap/index.php
    [SERVER_ADDR] => 11.1.1.1
    [SERVER_ADMIN] => root@localhost
    [SERVER_NAME] => example.com
    [SERVER_PORT] => 80
    [SERVER_PROTOCOL] => HTTP/1.1
    [SERVER_SIGNATURE] => 
    [SERVER_SOFTWARE] => Apache
    [UNIQUE_ID] => WASuooHowGwAAFv9EK4AAAAB
    [PHP_SELF] => /soap/index.php
    [REQUEST_TIME] => 1476701858
)
```

and the data:

```
xml: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
<soap12:Body>
<EditionContactCustomer xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
<Title>Spares</Title>
<FirstName>John</FirstName>
<Surname>Mc</Surname>
<AddressLine1></AddressLine1>
<PostTown>plett</PostTown>
<County>Western Cape</County>
<PostCode></PostCode>
<email>john@example.com</email>
<TelephoneNumber>081</TelephoneNumber>
<MobileNumber>081</MobileNumber>
<WorkTelephoneNumber></WorkTelephoneNumber>
<Notes>this is a test note.</Notes>
<ContactDate>2016-10-17</ContactDate>
<ContactTime>10:57:38</ContactTime>
<VehicleRecordID></VehicleRecordID>
<IntroductionSource>Existing</IntroductionSource>
<EnquirySource>WEB</EnquirySource>
<EnquiryType>WEB_FORM</EnquiryType>
<GUID></GUID>
<ReferenceID></ReferenceID>
<UserName></UserName>
<LinkUrl></LinkUrl>
<ImageData></ImageData>
</EditionContactCustomer>
</soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>
```

Comment: What's your actual PHP code?

Comment: sorry, I forgot to mention that I'm actually not using a SOAP client. I just create xml and then use curl to post it.. The output above is the result of the curl posting..

Comment: But....... why?

Answer (score 0):

To properly send SOAP 1.2 you need the correct "soap_version" param in the SoapClient construction.

```
$client = new SoapClient($url, array(
    "soap_version"      => SOAP_1_2,
    "login"             => "username",
    "password"          => "password"
));
```

Where $url is your WSDL location, online or file://